# Robotic Tasks in relation with components

Tags: kinematics, robotics-toolbox

I will try to ask the best i can: 
Our Human Body has parts like arms, legs, head etc. An arm can rotate 360 degrees. Arm has a hand with five fingers which can grip, poke, push etc.
How would we address the same for a robot in technical terms? 

I am really sorry if i do not explain it well enough ( my english is not very good).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is pretty vague, but I am assuming that you are looking for a mathematical representation of a robot in terms of DoFs. We have Denavit-Hartenberg parameters to describe robot arms. I suggest you look search for more information on D-H parameters. There are questions and answers on this website about this subject as well. I suggest you look into Spong's Robot Modeling and Control to learn more about these.

Other than that, I am not sure what else you are asking for as your question is vague.

Comment: Thank you @robotsfoundme, i will search and study what you meantioned above.